# Send Ajax request after seen the element by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to send an ajax query after user saw an element. For example there is an ul tag which show a list of news, after user saw element it sends ajax query to recieve and show the news in ul tag.

**Notice that I'm using the Vuejs framework.**

For example, something like this:

```
<template>
    <div @WHEN_VIEWED="sendAjax">
        <ul v-if="news">
            <li v-for="new in news">{{ new.title }}</li>
        </ul>
        <div v-else>
            Please Wait...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        name: "...",
        data() {
            return {
                news: null,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            sendAjax() {
                // Send Ajax...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lifecycle hooks` for making request during the component lifecycle.

For your problem, I would suggest - `mounted`

**Mounted (DOM Is Ready and Placed Inside the Page)** is get initiated after your component get rendered to `DOM`.

They allow you to access your component immediately before and after the first render. They do not, however, run during server-side rendering.

For reference - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

```
<template>
    <div @WHEN_VIEWED="sendAjax">
        <ul v-if="news" v-for="new in news">
        </ul>
        <div v-else>
            Please Wait...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        name: "...",
        data() {
            return {
                news: null,
            };
        },
        mounted() {
          this.sendAjax()
        },
        methods: {
            sendAjax() {
                // Send Ajax...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
try this

<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-if="news.length">
            <li v-for="new in news">{{ new.title }}</li>
        </ul>
        <div v-else>
            Please Wait...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        name: "...",
        data() {
            return {
                news: [],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            async sendAjax() {
                // Send Ajax...
            }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.news = await this.$axios.$get(`...`)
          })
        }
    }
</script>
```